# Is there a way to search for equations in Word 2007 documents?

Tags: microsoft-word, search, equations, visual-basic

I have many large Word 2007 documents containing a few dozen equations each. Is there a way to locate the equations using Word's Find command, or do I have to hunt for them old-school?

I tried searching for a graphic (`^g`) and and field (`^d`), but that didn't do the trick. Am I missing something obvious? Might there be a way to do this using VB or some other trick?

**Update**

It appears that the go-to-equation feature is broken in Office 2007. The feature can be accessed from the "Go To" tab on Word's Find dialog.

See some discussion [here](http://www.keyongtech.com/5008929-go-to-equation-doesnt-work).

Also, in VB one can observe the following:

```
' Works: advances to the next footnote.
Sub GoToFootnote()
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToFootnote
End Sub

' Does nothing, even though wdGoToEquation is a
' documented item in the WdGoToItem enumeration.
Sub GoToEquation()
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToEquation
End Sub
```

**Work-around**

```
Find
-> More
-> Format
-> Font = Cambria Math   (or whatever font your equations use)
```

Comment: the [`Range.OMaths`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196821.aspx) collection should contain the equations

Answer (score 2):

You need the "Go To" dialog box. You can get it by typing ctrl + g or on the Home tab, click the drop down on the "Find" button and choose "Go To".

The Go To dialog box lets you go to equations. You'll see it on the list on the left side of the box.

Comment: Interesting. I can't believe it is in there and doesn't work as it should. Good find on that other article.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it that way.

Since Word always sets the default font Cambria Math, it is very easily solved.

1. Create a new style called, e.g. Equation
2. Advanced Find and Replace With
   Find: Font: Cambria Math
   Replace With: Style: Equation

Now you can change your equations all at once as often as you love to.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for unearthing this old post, but I had the same problem, and apparently, the "go to" feature only finds MathType equations, and probably also the equations entered with the old 3.0 equation editor, but not the ones produced with the `Alt+=` command. The workaround proposed is indeed the only way I see working.

I just wanted to add that piece of information!

Answer (score 0):

This statement (in Word 2010 at least) will tell you how many OMML equations there are in the file:

ActiveDocument.OMaths.Count

This statement will select the first OMML equation in the file:

ActiveDocument.OMaths(1).Range.Select

Answer (score 0):

Though the OP asks a solution for Word 2007, the following is a **solution for Word 2019**.

Assume that in a Word 2019 doucment we wanna search a mathematical symbol (such as γ) entered via Equation Editor.
In the Home tab, click the small arrow near Find.
Click to Find Advanced.
In the Find tab, click to Font and select Cambria Math for font.
In the search area, paste the to-be-searched mathematical expression (such as γ) that was created via Equation Editor in a Word document.
Click Find next. Voila.

Such a search finds capital Γ besides lowercase γ.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to work at least in Word 2019, Version 2201 Build 16.0.14827.20180. I posted a question here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/756308/can39t-search-for-content-in-equation-in-word-2019.html