# Searching inside equations in MS word 2013

Tags: search, microsoft-word-2013, equations, equation-editor

I have a question similar to [this previously-asked question](https://superuser.com/questions/140374/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-equations-in-word-2007-documents). But, mine is different.

How can I search **inside** the equations I have written in MS-word 2013?

Answer (score 0):

For simple searches, like finding a Unicode character, the most convenient solution I found is to export/print the document as PDF and search using the pdf viewer (e.g. your browser). Unlike the Professional math equations, symbols are stored as actual Unicode characters in pdf files.